# Compile error cmark Erlang Phoenix on Windows

Tags: erlang, phoenix-framework, cmark

I am trying to run a Phoenix server on Windows.

On running `mix deps.get` the following result is given

```
`Running dependency resolution
* Getting cmark (Hex package)
Checking package (https://repo.hex.pm/tarballs/cmark-0.6.10.tar)
Using locally cached package`
```

Then when running `mix ecto.create` the following error is given

```
`C:\Users\alex\Documents\Alex Docs\Datamo\githubrepo\datamo>mix ecto.create
===> Compiling idna
==> cmark
could not compile dependency :cmark, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile 
this dependency with "mix deps.compile cmark", update it with 
"mix deps.update cmark" or clean it with "mix deps.clean cmark"
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :enoent
(elixir) lib/system.ex:544: System.cmd("make", [], [stderr_to_stdout: true])
mix.exs:85: Mix.Tasks.Compile.Cmark.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1184: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:19: anonymous fn/1 in
Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:37:
Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.with_logger_app/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.ex:84: Mix.Tasks.Compile.run/1`
```

Attempting to run `mix deps.compile cmark` creates an error

```
`** (Mix) Cannot compile dependency :cmark because it isn't available, run "mix deps.get" first`
```

But that was already run in the first stage with the error shown above. It seems to be stuck in a loop.

Is this because it's unable to unpack the tar file on windows?

Comment: Looks like `make` isn't present on your system.

Comment: Hi @Dogbert -  I've run the command cmd /k "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 and I can compile other dependencies that require make, as far as I know. Seems to be specifically a problem with cmark on Windows?